# REST API JSON value from CURL command into table format in UNIX

Tags: json, shell, unix

I have a shell script with `curl -s http://ifconfig.me/all.json` command which prints below output in the terminal window.

```
{
  "version" : {
  "ip_addr": "201.73.103.12",
  "lang": "java",
  "remote_host": "OpenSSL/0.9.8w zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.23 libssh2/1.2.2",",
  "user_agent": "curl/7.23.1 (i386-sun-solaris2.11) libcurl/7.23.1 
  "charset": "",
  "port": "63713"}
}
```

I need to display the JSON value in table format.

Someone, please help me with this to implement in UNIX shell script. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think any shell comes with built-in JSON parsing so you're either going to end up with a mess of a regexp or extra dependencies. I'm assuming you want this in shellscript to avoid deps. Since you're going to get them anyways if you do this properly, can't you just do this in a proper programming language?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the cool command-line JSON query parser / formatter tool:

http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

You can pipe your JSON input into this tool and extract out / format the keys you need.

Or, just run multiple `curl -s http://ifconfigme/` calls for each "row/column" you need and output it in some sane format, E.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

ip=`curl -s http://ifconfig.me/ip`
host=`curl -s http://ifconfig.me/host`

echo -e "ip\thost"
echo -e "${ip}\t${host}"
```

Comment: Is it possible to move the values in an array and then iterate?